# Hyperlink in a dynamic list

Tags: excel, search, dynamic, hyperlink

So i am hoping this is even do able.

i have created a dynamic search using the following link:
https://trumpexcel.com/dynamic-excel-filter/

This works great and i have no issues with it, EXCEPT to when it comes to hyperlinks on the primary data page. they will not show up on the view able page as an actual link.

here is an example: if sheet 1 is the view able sorting sheet, and sheet 2 is the main raw data. and my range is say A1:F10. if i put a hyperlink on sheet 2 at D5 then it should show this on sheet 1.  it states the text, but dos not carry over the link.  is this even possible.  please let me know. thank you

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "it states the text, but dos not carry over the link." how are you creating a hyperlink? is it a formula?

Comment: i am using the insert hyperlink function within excel, on the raw data sheet. i would have the text "click here".  the hyperlink works on the raw data sheet, but when you now go to the visual sheet(dynamic sheet) all it gives you is standard text of "click here".  hopefully that helps

Comment: This might not be possible without a macro, [solution using a macro](https://superuser.com/questions/593492/can-i-use-an-excel-formula-to-extract-the-link-location-of-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can return a hyperlink from a cell in another sheet referenced in a formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D5"),Sheet1!D5)
```